# Two concurrent AsyncTasks in Android - How to handle race conditions?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, thread-safety

I send an HTTP Post every time a button is pressed and every time it is released. It is likely that I will not have a response from the 'pressed' POST before the button is released, therefore I try to run these tasks concurrently. However, occasionally, the POST request for releasing the button is sent to the server before the request for pressing the button. How can I avoid/fix this?

```
button = (ImageButton) findViewById((R.id.button1));
        button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                HTTPAsyncTask task = new HTTPAsyncTask();
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ) {
                    task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, Utilities.StringCollection.rotateRight);
                    return true;
                }
                else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, Utilities.StringCollection.stop);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

If your min SDK is 11 "HONEYCOMB" you can call asyncTask like this to run it in single thread to prevent race condition between them:

```
button = (ImageButton) findViewById((R.id.button1));
        button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                HTTPAsyncTask task = new HTTPAsyncTask();
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ) {
                    task.execute(Utilities.StringCollection.rotateRight);// using one thread
                    return true;
                }
                else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    task.execute(Utilities.StringCollection.stop);// using one thread
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

**IMPORTANT**:  network I/O is not reliable and network packages may lost or may not receive in the sequence that they were sent but i saw the question in title

> "Two concurrent AsyncTasks in Android - How to handle race conditions?
>   "

and just answered that. Thus you can not be sure that one request is received after another in this way. I suggest you to send two events in one request to server and in server analyse it.

Comment: Two different touch events, means two different `HTTPAsyncTasks`, means each will be able to execute on its own thread. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @greeble31 i only change `executeOnExecutor` with `execute` all other codes is unchanged. it is @AndroidNewbie1 codes in his question

Comment: @greeble31 you are missing that two `AsyncTask` do not means two different threads all the times.Since api 11 if you do NOT run them on thread pool you run them in one worker thread. And if you run them in one worker thread they will run one after another has been complete even it is not important which `AsyncTask` instance you are using all `AsyncTask`  will run in one worker thread. But if you use `executeOnExecutor` they will be on different threads in parallel.

Comment: Alright, I did not know that, but unfortunately I cannot remove my downvote until the question is edited. However I'd like to point out this still doesn't address the original problem, which is that the OP desires to allow certain operations to execute in parallel. This answer ensures they execute serially, post-HONEYCOMB. See my answer for reference.

Comment: @greeble31 I know that network I/O is not reliable and network packages may lost or may not receive in the sequence that they were send but i saw the question in title "Two concurrent AsyncTasks in Android - How to handle race conditions?
" and just answered that. i will update my answer to point this.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, your `HTTPAsyncTask` `doInBackground()` consists of 2 distinct actions:

1. Connect, and queue the request to socket
2. Receive the response

(after which, of course, `onPostExecute()` will be called.)

As you've described, you need to control the order of execution for action #1, on two different threads, while allowing action #2 to occur in parallel.

This is not possible using the generic `AsyncTask` mechanism, because you have not provided any way to "split the task in two"; there is no way for thread A to figure out when thread B has switched from action #1 to action #2, or vice versa.

It's possible such logic could be added, but you have not explained how you're making the socket call.

There's little point in providing that extra detail, however; the edge cases associated with the network request(s) destroy any guarantee of order you might've had. Networks are lossy; requests may fail, responses may fail. Requests may *arrive* out-of-order even though they were *sent* in order (particularly if you are using two separate sockets). Automatic re-tries may take several seconds to accomplish.

IOW, the "pressed" request may get lost by the network, and you may have to re-queue it to the socket sometime after the "unpressed" request has completed.

I would advise that you give up on the "partial conditional concurrency" you are seeking, and simply ensure that the first `HTTPAsyncTask` has completed before you execute the second one.

Alternatively, you could add a sequential "request ID" to each POST, or include information about the first request *in* the second request, so that the server is able to sort out what has happened, even if the requests arrive out-of-order.